# as3, rotating image and then moving x and y relative to center

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am in the midst of finishing up a design application where you can upload images and colors. I use the greensock transform manager.  I am taking anything a user does and recording it so I can recreate what they made on larger scale behind the scenes (to be exported for printing purposes)

The problem I am running into is with rotation and moving x and y values. The transform manager does everything relative to a center point, but when i recreate the image object the registration point is at the top left. I have found how to rotate around the center of the object using the transform matrix, but I can't seem to move the x and y correctly because these values change when you rotate. I want to just move the image to the left or right relative to the center. How could I go about doing this.

Here is how I rotate.

```
private function rotateAroundCenter (ob:*, angleDegrees:Number, ptRotationPoint:Point) {
      var m:Matrix=ob.transform.matrix;
      m.tx -= ptRotationPoint.x;
      m.ty -= ptRotationPoint.y;
      m.rotate (angleDegrees*(Math.PI/180));
      m.tx += ptRotationPoint.x;
      m.ty += ptRotationPoint.y;
      ob.transform.matrix=m;
 }
```

EDIT:
Here is some more code when I am transforming the items (this is after I changed some things according to the first comment below. (the _j2sratio is what I am sizing everything up to for printing).

```
var newUI:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var bmapHolder:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
bmapHolder.addChild(bmap);
bmapHolder.x = -bmapHolder.width/2;
bmapHolder.y = -bmapHolder.height/2;
newUI.addChild(bmapHolder);
newUI.width = $value.twidth * _j2sRatio;
newUI.height = $value.theight * _j2sRatio;
newUI.rotation = $value.rotation;
bmapHolder.scaleX = $value.scaleX * _newScale;
bmapHolder.scaleY = $value.scaleY * _newScale;
newUI.x = $value.positionX * _j2sRatio;
newUI.y = $value.positionY * _j2sRatio;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you have a sprite/movieClip that you apply the transformations to, and have the bitmap location offset by `-width/2` and `-height/2` for `x` and `y` respectively ?

Comment: well I have tried this but some strange things are happening. I am using flex and some ui components, so not sure if that has anything to do with it.